# How to use searchable.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I read lots of posts on this but I actually don't understand how it works:
I created a searchable.xml in the xml folder:

[image]

Then I referenced it to my Manifest like this:

[image]

I can't figure out how can I use it in the search code, I tried with the SearchManager but without success:

```
SearchView searchView;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new SearchQueryEvent(s));
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Which part of the code is not working and in which activity is it placed?

Comment: I actually don't know what's wrong with it. It is placed in an activity with a toolbar and the searchView is a part of the toolbar. My question is: "Why can't I see my searchable settings in the application?" @AR.3