# How to implement searchable.xml?

Tags: android

Recently, I have come across the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#TheBasics) for search dialogue provided by the Android developer. In their documentation, they mentioned about a searchable.xml which is a configuration file for something that I don't get it. I know that you are supposed to reference this file in the manifest and that's about it.

**Addtionally**, this post practically a repost of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41512459/how-to-use-searchable-xml). But there wasn't any answer so I hope it can be answered here.

**Questions**

My question is, does this searchable.xml a configuration file for your searchView where you can implement this searchView anywhere in your activity layout ?

Is there any useful reference I can refer ? Most of the videos I came across such as Coding In Flow and Edmt Dev do not use this xml file at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good amount of research, searchable.xml is tied to search view. The docs provide a good amount of guide but not an extensive one.

Hence, I would recommend users to look up for floating Search View as it is way easier than implementing searchable.xml and searchView.